# How to automatically create Azure DevOps Boards backups for point in time restore?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

Azure DevOps Service doesn’t have an out of the box [feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1249654/support-point-in-time-recovery-backup-and-restore.html) to support point in time backup/restore for Azure **Boards**. Therefore, I am wondering how to do this via APIs?

I am open to any option that could be automatically scheduled.  For example, on a scheduled basis (pipeline) create and store a backup that could potentially be used to do a manually triggered restore in the future.

Although the UI supports [exporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#export-list-as-csv)/[importing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops) work item data to/from CSV, I was not able to find a corresponding API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I further checked this problem. Currently, there is no REST API for importing work items from .CSV file. Please check this [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/939799/azure-rest-api-to-import-work-items-from-csv-file.html), and then you could directly vote and add comments on it.

For a workaround, please check the steps below:

1. PowerShell task to call [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get-results-of-a-flat-work-item-query) to get results of a flat work item query, we can get all work item ids from the response body.
2. Use the work item id to call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples), and then get the detailed information of the work items.
3. Save the response body of the work item details obtained by batch into a json file, and then use the **Publish Pipeline Artifacts** task to publish this file to Artifact, achieve the purpose of backup.
4. Use the **Download Pipeline Artifacts** task to download artifact files.
5. Use PowerShell task to call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/WorkItemBatchUpdate?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) below to achieve the purpose of restore.

For example:

```
PATCH https://{organization}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/$batch?api-version=4.1
```

Body:

```
[{
        
        "method": "PATCH",
        
        "uri": "/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${work item type}?api-version=4.1",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
        },
        "body": [{
                "op": "add",
                "path": "/id",
                "value": "-1"
            },
            {
                "op": "add",
                "path": "/fields/System.Title",
                "from": null,
                "value": "Sample 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "method": "PATCH",
        "uri": "/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${work item type}?api-version=4.1",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
        },
        "body": [{
                "op": "add",
                "path": "/id",
                "value": "-2"
            },
            {
                "op": "add",
                "path": "/fields/System.Title",
                "from": null,
                "value": "Sample 2"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

To [configure the scheduled trigger for a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic), please check the steps below:

1. Switch to the **Triggers** tab, click the **Add** button behind Scheduled to add a schedule.
2. Select the days and times when you want to run the build.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I voted on the uservoice.  I like the pipeline artifact option, but another alternative would be storing in a git repo (diffing may be useful).

Comment: I also added a new feature request and edited my question to link to it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1249654/support-point-in-time-recovery-backup-and-restore.html